# issue with loop after invoking void function arduino

Tags: arduino

i've made simple program that is ligtning the RGB diod, and receiving info via i2c from keypad.

i have weird issue where i2c is not working right after invoking void function. when i switch functions with regular loop then same situation happens.

first i thought that it was connected with analog4 and analog5 port, but after changing functions it became obvious that this is not related.

after commenting Potentiometer(i) in loop method keypad is working as a charm

beneath i'm putting code

```
    #include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_MPR121.h"

Adafruit_MPR121 cap = Adafruit_MPR121();
uint16_t lasttouched = 0;
uint16_t currtouched = 0;

int RGB1[] = { 22, 23, 24 };
int RGB2[] = { 25, 26, 27 };
int RGB3[] = { 28, 29, 30 };
int RGB4[] = { 31, 32, 33 };

void setup()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  pinMode(RGB1[i], OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RGB1[i], HIGH);
  pinMode(RGB2[i], OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RGB2[i], HIGH);
  pinMode(RGB3[i], OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RGB3[i], HIGH);
  pinMode(RGB4[i], OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RGB4[i], HIGH);
}

Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Adafruit MPR121 Capacitive Touch sensor test");
if (!cap.begin(0x5A)) {
  Serial.println("MPR121 not found, check wiring?");
  while (1);
}
Serial.println("MPR121 found!");
}

void loop()
{
  currtouched = cap.touched();

 for (uint8_t i=0; i<12; i++) {
   // it if *is* touched and *wasnt* touched before, alert!
   if ((currtouched & _BV(i)) && !(lasttouched & _BV(i)) ) {
     Serial.print(i); Serial.println(" touched");
   }
   // if it *was* touched and now *isnt*, alert!
   if (!(currtouched & _BV(i)) && (lasttouched & _BV(i)) ) {
     Serial.print(i); Serial.println(" released");
   }
 }

 // reset our state
 lasttouched = currtouched;

 Potentiometer(0);
 Potentiometer(1);
 Potentiometer(2);
 Potentiometer(3);

 // comment out this line for detailed data from the sensor!
 return;

 // debugging info, what
 Serial.print("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t 0x"); Serial.println(cap.touched(), HEX);
 Serial.print("Filt: ");
 for (uint8_t i=0; i<12; i++) {
   Serial.print(cap.filteredData(i)); Serial.print("\t");
 }
 Serial.println();
 Serial.print("Base: ");
 for (uint8_t i=0; i<12; i++) {
   Serial.print(cap.baselineData(i)); Serial.print("\t");
 }
 Serial.println();


 delay(100);
}



void Potentiometer(int i){
  int j = analogRead(i);

  switch (i+1){
    case 1:
    detectColor(RGB1, j);
    break;

    case 2:
    detectColor(RGB2, j);
    break;

    case 3:
    detectColor(RGB3, j);
    break;

    case 4:
    detectColor(RGB4, j);
    break;
  }
 }

 void detectColor(int i[], int j){
  if (j < 25)
  RGB_color(i, 0);

  if (j > 25 && j < 195)
  RGB_color(i, 1);

  if (j > 195 && j < 365)
  RGB_color(i, 2);

  if (j > 365 && j < 535)
  RGB_color(i, 3);

  if (j > 535 && j < 705)
  RGB_color(i, 4);

  if (j > 705 && j < 875)
  RGB_color(i, 5);

  if (j > 875 && j < 1010)
  RGB_color(i, 6);

  if (j > 1010)
  RGB_color(i, 7);
 }

 void RGB_color(int dioda[], int color)
 {
   switch (color){
     case 0:
     digitalWrite(dioda[0], HIGH);
     digitalWrite(dioda[1], HIGH);
     digitalWrite(dioda[2], HIGH);
     break;
     case 1:
     digitalWrite(dioda[0], LOW);
     digitalWrite(dioda[1], HIGH);
     digitalWrite(dioda[2], HIGH);
     break;
     case 2:
     digitalWrite(dioda[0], HIGH);
     digitalWrite(dioda[1], LOW);
     digitalWrite(dioda[2], HIGH);
     break;
     case 3:
     digitalWrite(dioda[0], HIGH);
     digitalWrite(dioda[1], HIGH);
     digitalWrite(dioda[2], LOW);
     break;
     case 4:
     digitalWrite(dioda[0], LOW);
     digitalWrite(dioda[1], LOW);
     digitalWrite(dioda[2], HIGH);
     break;
     case 5:
     digitalWrite(dioda[0], LOW);
     digitalWrite(dioda[1], HIGH);
     digitalWrite(dioda[2], LOW);
     break;
     case 6:
     digitalWrite(dioda[0], HIGH);
     digitalWrite(dioda[1], LOW);
     digitalWrite(dioda[2], LOW);
     break;
     case 7:
     digitalWrite(dioda[0], LOW);
     digitalWrite(dioda[1], LOW);
     digitalWrite(dioda[2], LOW);
     break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: @Olaf thank You. now I will patch my software easilly :)

Comment: Try declaring functions on top of the file

Comment: @dubafek this didn't help either :/

Comment: Just to be sure. Did you declared them like this?
`void detectColor(int[], int);`
`void Potentiometer(int);`
Or you just moved them all up?

Comment: sorry for late answer. i guess this is not fault of the code, beacuse i have simillar isues, but when using 3 i2c modules. program is stoping after first line of void setup() Serial.println("something); I will try to debug it, and see if maybe serial is blocking software(?).

and it isn't. my board is also correct, because same issues are on different boards. so this is either my software fault (doubtly, because even hardware providers checked it), or libraries (even more doubtly) so only thing that remains is magic.

Comment: and about your question, i have checked both version. declaring whole method at the upper part of code, and declaring object earlier.